# In what ways is Greenify different from regular task killers?

Tags: task-management, greenify

When I say "regular" task killers I mean the ones that don't use root privileges or Xposed Framework and are often quite simple.

At first I thought that one difference between [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) and regular task killers is that regular task killers require the user to manually kill tasks, whereas Greenify can operate continuously without the user worrying about its operation. But then I noticed that some task killers have an "auto" feature now too. Actually, Greenify also has a "non-root" mode now, which I am guessing would be similar to that.

In this question I'm talking about Greenify in "root-mode" and with the Xposed module active.

What differences are there? Should Greenify be called a task killer, or is it something more? What does Greenify utilise its root privileges and Xposed module for? What sets Greenify apart from regular task killers? What are the benefits and/or disadvantages of using Greenify as compared to a regular task killer?